# What do the double-less-than and pipe operators do?

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What does this line do?

```
$theVal = ((($theR << 8) | $theG) << 8) | $theB;
```

What do the `<<` and `|` do?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are Bitwise operators that allow evaluation and manipulation of specific bits within an integer.

$a | $b Or Bits that are set in either $a or $b are set.

$a << $b    Shift left   Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

$a >> $b    Shift right  Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the right (each step means "divide by two")

Answer (score 3):

The literal answer can be found by reading about [Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Practically speaking, it converts 3 values for Red, Blue and Green bytes into a single 24bit RGB value.